# Python tkinter classes changing icon

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, class, tkinter

I'm not that familar with classes or tkinter, but what i'm trying to do is, if 
test1 is selected, than change the icon too favicon, i can't really figure it out, if you could help me that would be great, and if i'm doing something wrong

```
from tkinter import *


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.iconnum = IntVar()
        master.title('Testing')
        master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        master.maxsize(500, 250)
        master.minsize(500, 250)

        self.test1= Radiobutton(master, text="test1", variable=0, value=1, )
        self.test2= Radiobutton(master, text="test2", variable=0, value=2, )
        self.test3= Radiobutton(master, text="test3", variable=0, value=3, )
        self.test4= Radiobutton(master, text="test4", variable=0, value=4,  )

        self.test1.grid(row=2, columnspan=1)
        self.test2.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
        self.test3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.test4.grid(row=3, columnspan=1,)

        self.Test5= Radiobutton(master, text="Test5", indicatoron=0, height=1, width=35,  value=0, command=self.icon_switcher)
        self.Test6= Radiobutton(master, text="Test6", indicatoron=0, height=1, width=35, value=1, command=self.icon_switcher)

        self.Test5.grid(row=1)
        self.Test6.grid(row=1, column=1,)

    def icon_switcher(self):
        if self.iconnum == 1:
            self.master.iconbitmap('favicon.ico')




root = Tk()
gui = GUI(root)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give a tkinter `IntVar`for  `RadioButton`'s `variable` keyword:

Change

```
self.test1= Radiobutton(master, text="test1", variable=0, value=1, )
```

to

```
self.test1= Radiobutton(master, text="test1", variable=self.iconnum, value=1, )
```

This will record the selected value in the `IntVar`.
Then in the `icon_switcher` function you can call `self.iconnum.get()` to get the selected value.

Comment: I just added what you said and this happened, also my problem is I don't know how to call master.iconbitmap('favicon.ico') if iconnum == 1

Comment: @nooby Did you change all the required `Radiobutton`'s variables to `self.iconnum`? I can't reproduce the 2 value error on my pc. Regarding `icon_switcher` You can use an `if`statement to check the iconnum value. For example: `if self.iconnum.get() == 1: self.master.iconbitmap("icon1.png")`

Comment: No I didn't change all of them, also, my IDE (pycharm) says this Unresolved attribute reference 'master' for class 'GUI'

Comment: when attempting self.master.iconbitmap("icon1.png")

Comment: Change the variable of Radiobuttons 1 through 4. Also add `self.master = master` right after defining `__init__()`